# Is SNMP MIB important for SNMP agent?

Tags: snmp

It is obvious that MIBs are important for network management stations as otherwise SNMP queries based on object names would not work. For example:

```
$ snmpget -M /dir/that/does/not/exist -On -v 2c -c public 10.10.10.1 sysUpTimeInstance 2>/dev/null 
$ snmpget -M /dir/that/does/not/exist -On -v 2c -c public 10.10.10.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 2>/dev/null 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (69843635) 8 days, 2:00:36.35
$
```

However, either one queries based on object name or OID, the SNMP get-request message sent to SNMP agent still obviously contains only the OID. What is the role of MIBs on SNMP agents? Or am I correct that MIB databases have nothing to do with SNMP agents?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Agent doesn't use MIB, it operates only on OID level.  Manager needs MIB to decode/encode OID's to/from readable format.

Answer (score 0):

MIBs are very much related to [SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org) agents.  The MIB is the mechanism through which an agent exposes data for the management of the managed device.  Here is an [MIB example](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt) that I found useful when first learning about the interactions of agents, MIBs, managed devices, and managers.  MIBs provided by the manufacturers of networking equipment can provide a huge number configuration and management options over SNMP.  This is particularly true in the cases of servers with dedicated NICs for Baseboard Management Controllers(BMCs) which can provide out-of-band management via SNMP.

Modern datacenter monitoring/management software like [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org) or [Intel Datacenter Manager](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/intel-dcm-product-detail.html) can offer mechanisms for discovery of connected SNMP agents and their MIBs, allowing for graphical management of some aspects of SNMP networks.