# Are SNMP MIB files in NMS required if NMS will poll data from SNMP agent using OIDs directly?

Tags: snmp

I plan to [write a MIB module](http://net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_MIB_Module) for [Net-SNMP SNMP agent](http://net-snmp.org) so that my NMS can ask a value of certain custom OID from SNMP agent. As I don't mind using directly OID instead of object name in NMS, then am I correct that I don't need to [write a MIB file](http://net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_own_MIBs)?

Comment: Yeah, usually just using the OID should work fine, though I have seen some cases where software demanded a name when it didn't really need it due to bad assumptions.

Comment: @SteveWills Thanks! Did you meant that NMS demanded a name when it didn't really need it due to bad assumptions?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214573/is-snmp-mib-important-for-snmp-agent

Answer (score 0):

@Steve is right - MIB is not needed in case that handling of SNMP communication is done by the system you write and you are OK with numeric OIDs.

SNMP MIBs are useful in case that the interface between an agent and a manager needs to be described. Writing a proper MIB can even save you some time if you are using some automatic code generation (`net-snmp mib2c`).